What would be left after 150,000 years
In the story I'm writing a human is landing on a planet of a far advanced alien civilization that went extinct. The reason for that is "unknown" so there was no war or natural catastrophe. No bombs that destroyed anything. No barbarians that dismantled older buildings.
The species itself was far advanced to the space age (having satellite and space ships etc.) so we can assume their buildings last a bit longer than current ones and they have built some "mega structures" like the Pyramids on earth or these fictional buildings like the  Shadowrun Renraku Arcology.
The planet itself contains a "normal" amount of plants and animals that might regrow or use the now empty cities but would not actively reshape the environment like humans did. The environment itself has a more active weather than on earth (meaning more rain, stronger wind, few sandstorms).
Now that humanity arrives here about 100,000 - 200,000 years after their extinction/disappearance, I wonder what might be left of them.
Specifically I wonder:

What would be left of their cities (assuming their buildings were build with advanced architecture in mind)? How long could buildings like the Great Chinese Wall or the Pyramids exist before they are turned into dust?
What would a reasonably well trained archaeologist still find after such a long time? Like cars, trains, ships or even consumer goods? Would rain and wind tear these into pieces of dust and rust?
Would their "way of living" be understandable? For instance: could you still make out places of agriculture? I assume the plants will overgrow after a few decades already but maybe by finding old machines etc.

So basically: how much could you discover from such an ancient civilization or dust be the only thing that's left of them?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

We've had a lot of questions about what would remain after x period after a civilisation died - please have a look at those questions and see if they answer yours.  I also suggest that you clarify the period you are considering - I'm assuming that you are meaning one hundred thousand years to two hundred thousand years, but using a period rather than a comma makes it read as 100 years (to 3 decimal places) to most users on this site.  Finally, note that buildings today are often not made to last indefinitely - even without Deus, the arcology in Seattle would not have lasted very long.

Thanks for the hint. Yes I saw some similar questions. They were however slightly different since they mostly asked for 10,000 years and/or humanity.
Of course current buildings aren't meant to last for eternity which is why I brought up the pyramids as another example.

Some of the things made by humans likely to last for tens of thousands of years and maybe longer aren't even going to be in the solar system in tens of thousands of years - the Voyager probes. So instead of relying on random chance - and extremely aggressive archeology without knowing that there was something to look for - you could invert the setup if you wanted: humans in the year 2XXX detect ET Voyager and trace it back to a star of origin fifty light years away and tens or hundreds of thousands of years ago.

this depends a lot on the location, in the desert quite a lot, in the jungle maybe concrete. Lots of artifacts will survive, buried glass will basically last for billions of years.

VTC:Too Story-Based. You didn't read similar Qs, you read the same Q answered over and over. What did watching the TV series Life After People fail to teach you? What narrative necessity must we adhere to? How many biomes are we to consider? Over that much time, the ecology of almost every square inch of the planet will change. How much Clarkean Magic are we dealing with? You're asking as if there is a deterministic answer ...

... when the only deterministic answer is what you require for the purpose of your story. From the perspective of this Stack, it's preferable to tell us what you need to survive and ask for help rationalizing that survival (in the specific environment you require) rather than asking for an entire encyclopedia of archeology for a fictional environment and fictional technology - which is out of scope.

I don't think this is Off topic as it's been closed for, but it does need more detail for an answer .. what materials are being used and what erosive forces and other process are acting on them are necessary details that are needed

Without knowing exactly what makes their building materials and architecture more durable than ours, the answer is probably still "pretty much nothing". Our technology won't last even half that long, so these guys will need to last more than "a bit" longer. Especially with more extreme weather, which is the main force driving erosion and corrosion.
That's also a significant amount of time geologically, many things that survive long enough will get buried quite deeply and the surrounding landscape will change so much that it won't be obvious it was ever a place someone might try to build something.
Even if an archaeologist with enough technology and wit could find and uncover those buried ruins, the odds are quite low that enough would remain to accurately infer much detail about their way of life. Chemical composition of soil and rock might differ noticeably in some places, and on closer inspection the unusual composition might form vaguely artificial shapes resembling building foundations or road beds. With enough analysis and luck you might even be able to roughly map an entire city, but pretty much any attempt to determine the purpose of any structure on that map would be little more than speculation, and therefore it would be difficult to scientifically infer anything about the culture from it.
Archaeologists studying humans usually have the benefit of extensive documentation and experience with the most recent descendants of the people they study and the historical records they've inherited, making the guesswork a little easier. For a dead alien civilization, however, there's literally zero context, so every guess is based purely on human intuition and is therefore likely to be super wrong.
Of course, there's always a chance that something could just happen to be preserved in just the right way to last just long enough for your explorers to find in a useful state, but that will be the extremely rare exception. And again, without context, it's pretty unlikely that anyone will be able to fully understand it.
